# What may be the condition of the first stages of Saturn V splashed into ocean after separation?

Tags: saturn-v, engines

Two [F-1 engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketdyne_F-1#Recovery) were recovered from a depth of 14,000 feet (4,300 m), about 400 miles (640 km) east of Cape Canaveral after 40 years in the ocean.

There is much damage caused by splash down but very little caused by corrosion of salt water to be seen in this image:

[image]

[Inconel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inconel) alloys are oxidation-corrosion-resistant materials used for many parts of the F-1.

But what about the other parts of the SI-C stage, the tanks and structures made from aluminium alloys with poor corrosion resistance? After splash down and more than 40 years in salt water there may be very few left on the ocean floor. Parts made of thin sheet metall will be fully dissolved.

Comment: I hadn't seen the cleaned-up version of the recovered F-1 before, very cool.

Comment: Thanks for adding the picture. It is a huge improvement of the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [collectspace](http://www.collectspace.com/news/news-032013a.html), here's a photo of part of an S-IC stage underwater after 40+ years:

[image]

It's hard to tell the condition of the alloy itself due to the overgrowth, but while shattered, it doesn't look badly corroded.

Comment: More impressive images [after](http://www.collectspace.com/news/news-032013b.html) the recovery and during [conservation](http://www.collectspace.com/news/news-052113b.html).

Comment: Very hard to tell what is missing due to splash down and what due to 40+ years in salt water.

Comment: The condition of the material in the bottom center along the dark/light seam appears very much intact; I don't think the salt water is corroding anything away.

Comment: There are aluminium alloys for shipbuilding with high corrosion resistance to sea water used for ship building and there are other alloys used for aircrafts with low corrosion resistance in sea water that are not suited to shipbuilding. I think it is unlikely that alloys for shipbuilding were used for the Saturn V. The aircraft company Boeing that build the first stage most likely used aircraft alloys with high mechanical strength but low corrosion resistance in sea water. Aircrafts may use several layers of paint for corrosion protection during decades, but not first stages.

Comment: I believe being completely and continuously immersed in seawater is much less corrosive than spending time at the ocean's surface, where both salt and plentiful free oxygen are available.

Comment: That is why salt water spray tests are done. I think that is the point "being completely and continuously immersed in seawater".